# Streamlit does not display external url option

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, streamlit

I'm running the streamlit demo-self-driving:

https://github.com/streamlit/demo-self-driving

first I'm trying on a lightsail instance as:

```
streamlit run https://raw.githubusercontent.com/streamlit/demo-self-driving/master/streamlit_app.py
```

I get the following response:

[image]

But when I run the same code on a EC2 p3.large instance I get this response:

[image]

The IP is a public one, hence I'm not able to open the interface from the local machine

Comment: Have you read this article? 
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-a-streamlit-app-using-an-amazon-free-ec2-instance-416a41f69dc3

Answer (score -1):

run with:
streamlit run your_app.py --server.headless=true